# Customer SQLServer installations - how to prevent performance issues

Tags: sql-server, performance, performance-testing

We have an off the shelf product and customers are buying licenses to use this. They install this on their servers. The database schema looks exactly the same at all customers but the usage differs a lot. One customer might be huge with its users and using one component and one customer might be small using several. It differs how they use it.

The problem is when it comes to performance tuning. I can always start a log/trace/extended events, check system views, activity monitor etc at the customer site when they are facing these issues. But the problem is that I don´t know what is normal - do the waits differ or so? Some technicians at the customer does not have the knowledge to log these.

I´m searching the internet for clues how to prevent performance issues like these at the customer site, but I don´t feel like I´m getting the answers I want, if there are any? :) Our test databases differs so much in how the data is distributed.

Anyone else working like this and have tips on how to prevent performance issues in all the ways possible? Some tips on third party tools or ways to work?

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered an active performance test before launch to appropriately tune the instance for its intended use?   IS this worth doing?   Ask what is the cost to the organization for the poor performance of the app or downtime?   If the risk is less than the cost of the performance testing effort then this would seem an easy decision.

Comment: Just talked to my boss and they support this kind of testing :) .But this sort of performance testing - how does that work in practice?

I thought about using a stress tool while testing the application/component and meanwhile logging what happens.

Or does someone have any other input about this procedure? :)

Comment: See tpc.org and the tpc-c documentation as an example of a benchmark for one mix of transactions.   Your load model will vary by customer.   Stress and Load are but two types of tests.  Load is at a defined level.  Stress is at an every increasing level to the point  of defined failure.   You will want to hire someone who has been there and bought the t shirt previously